# From point cloud to laser scan

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i can get the point cloud data from the OpenNI driver now, like to convert it into a laser scan.How do you do it? Any suggestions or directions that i can take?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10568/from-point-cloud-to-laser-scan/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) package should do what you need.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-14**:
its under turtlebot..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-14**:
I have it in /opt/ros/diamondback, unfortunately don't know which ubuntu package.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-07-12**:
I think this package does not come with the regular distribution of ROS Diamondback and has to be installed additionally

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-11**:
just to clarify something. Does this package come with ros diamondback? it has to be downloaded.. Am i right?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-07-11**:
Also, if you installed ROS from binaries, like the default instructions say, you can install the package from binaries too: "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-turtlebot"

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-07-11**:
That stack is under Mercurial version control, not SVN. First, "sudo apt-get install mercurial". Next, "hg clone [https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot"](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot%22)

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-11**:
to download just that package, i need to type svn co https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot   Am i right?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-11**:
thanks, will work on it..

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-11**:
turtlebot is an iRobot Create based robot by WillowGarage, all its supporting software and drivers (including pointcloud_to_laserscan package) is released for ROS Diamondback.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-11**:
this package is for turtlebot. what about diamondback?

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-08-21**:
Hi, I am using ros indigo and i need the same thing.
I connected the kinect, launch freenect.launch.
Then in a different terminal 'rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscanode'
and i am trying to get the data from the topic /scan. But It is showing nothing.

Can anyone suggest me ..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

---

Originally posted by [jajskadu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3495/jajskadu/) with karma: 11 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1